# Is there a way to quit Vim so that it will load the same session next time?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I have Vim running with a good number of tabs, buffers, etc, but I need to quit to reboot, install a new Vim version, etc.

But when I start Vim back up I want the same tabs, split windows, with the same files open in them.

**Is there any way to do this? Does Vim have a concept of "sessions"?**

(I'm not worried about tabs or buffers that contained contents not loaded from files.)

Comment: i think this is already answered here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642611/how-to-save-a-session-in-vim

Comment: @epoyraz: You, sir, are more useful than the **Related** section (-:

Answer (score 2):

Yeah of course VIM knows session managment :)

From the vim doc :

> A Vim session contains all the information about what you are
>   editing. This includes things such as the file list, window layout,
>   global variables, options and other information.  (Exactly what is
>   remembered is controlled by the 'sessionoptions' option, described
>   below.)    The following command creates a session file:
>
> :mksession vimbook.vim
>
> Later if you want to restore this session, you can use this command:
>
> :source vimbook.vim

Check out this tuto about this functionnality : http://usevim.com/2013/07/05/sessions/

Answer (score 2):

Make a session in Vim:

`:mksession session.vim`

In terminal, restore session:

`$ vim -S session.vim`

Or when already in Vim, restore session:

`:source session.vim`